# Stopping emails going into spam (Gmail, Hotmail etc) POSTFIX

Tags: email, dns, debian, spam, postfix-mta

My mail server receives a perfect score on mail-tester.com (10/10). It has DKIM, TLS, DNS all pointing the right ways etc but for some reason unbeknown to me it keeps going into all the spam filters on all major email providers. I'm really at a loss with this one. It's not listed on any spam lists also when you type in either my domain or IP. Any help would be appreciated. My domain is www.newagemarketingltd.co.uk.

Merry Christmas

Answer (score 0):

Do you use DMARC and SPF ? Have you check your domains / IP reputation on http://www.senderbase.org/ ?

Do you send email from script like php ? If yes you have to respect some rules on your scripts.

You can check : https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en